# Finding general solution using Euclid's extended algorithm

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

I have a problem where I'm supposed to find the general equation to $242x+1870y=66$.

I used Euclid's extended algorithm to find $x=8$ and $y=-1$, but am not sure how to find all possible solutions using this information.

Is there a formula I can plug into? or can someone assist me in finishing this problem?

Comment: divide through by 22, $11x+ 85y= 3.$  Since $11$ and $85$ are coprime, all solutions come from one seed solution, then add any multiple of $85t$ to $x,$  giving $x +85t,$ and replace $y$ by $y - 11t$

Comment: @WillJagy so finding x=8 and y= (-1) isn't needed?

Comment: $x=8, y=-1$ is what I referred to as the "seed" solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the homogenous equation ($242x + 1870y = 0$). Perhaps, the solutions to your equations are exactly the sum of your particular inhomogenous solution and a solution to the homogenous problem, since the equations are linear. (prove it!)

Now note that you can multiply both sides of the homogenous equation ad libitum to generate all solutions.